# Scala, generic tuple

Tags: scala, generics

I have a generic method that can accept any tuple of any size, the only constraint is that the first element of this tuple should be of type `MyClass`.

Something like this:

```
trait MyTrait[T <: (MyClass, _*)] {
  getMyClass(x: T): MyClass = x._1
}
```

I've tried this

```
trait MyTrait[T <: (MyClass, _) with (MyClass, _, _) with (MyClass, _, _) with ...] {
  getMyClass(x: T): MyClass = x._1
}
```

but I get the error `unboud wildcard type`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little bit unsafe but you can use Structural type in this case:

```
trait MyTrait {
  def getMyClass(x: {def _1: MyClass}): MyClass = x._1
}
```

Comment: This is [compound type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#compound-types) or "structural type" which, unlike "Duck typing", has a clearly-defined meaning is Scala.

Comment: This was surprisingly simple.

Comment: Just to strength constrain you may use `Product { def _1: MyClass }`, but it steel can accept case class with `def _1`

Comment: This is very simple to use, thank you. Anyway I had to enable reflective call, am I right?

Comment: It seems that with structural type the method _1 is called via reflection and this leads to poor performance.

Comment: @Gigitsu I believe this is compile time reflection, so the "poor performane" should be while compiling and not while running the code. right ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh actually I think is runtime reflection, because the method _1 is called via reflection, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do this without either boilerplate or runtime reflection, [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is your best bet. You can use the `IsComposite` type class to put type-level constraints on the first element of a tuple:

```
import shapeless.ops.tuple.IsComposite

trait MustBeFirst

class MyClass[P <: Product](p: P)(implicit ev: IsComposite[P] { type H = MustBeFirst }) {
  def getMustBeFirst(x: P): MustBeFirst = ev.head(p)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> val good2 = (new MustBeFirst {}, "")
good2: (MustBeFirst, String) = ($anon$1@7294acee,"")

scala> val good3 = (new MustBeFirst {}, "", 123)
good3: (MustBeFirst, String, Int) = ($anon$1@6eff9288,"",123)

scala> val good4 = (new MustBeFirst {}, "", 'xyz, 123)
good4: (MustBeFirst, String, Symbol, Int) = ($anon$1@108cdf99,"",'xyz,123)

scala> val bad2 = ("abc", 123)
bad2: (String, Int) = (abc,123)

scala> new MyClass(good2)
res0: MyClass[(MustBeFirst, String)] = MyClass@5297aa76

scala> new MyClass(good3)
res1: MyClass[(MustBeFirst, String, Int)] = MyClass@3f501844

scala> new MyClass(good4)
res2: MyClass[(MustBeFirst, String, Symbol, Int)] = MyClass@24e15478

scala> new MyClass(bad2)
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: shapeless.ops.tuple.IsComposite[(String, Int)]{type H = MustBeFirst}
       new MyClass(bad2)
       ^
```

If you need to use a trait, you can put the `ev` (for "evidence") requirement inside the definition instead of in the constructor:

```
trait MyTrait[P <: Product] {
  implicit def ev: IsComposite[P] { type H = MustBeFirst }
}
```

Now any class instantiating `MyTrait` will have to provide evidence that `P` is a tuple with `MustBeFirst` as its first element.

Comment: Probably nitpicking, but I if read shapeless source correctly, IsComposite will also witness that the tuple is of size at least 2. It may be a relevant detail for the asker since tuples of size 1, however awkward, are a thing ^^

Comment: @C4stor `IsComposite` works for `Tuple1`, with tail type being `Unit`.

Comment: Altought I like this solution and shapeless in general, I don't know how to use this in my case.
This is my actual use case: https://pastebin.com/yCKs0eiQ

Answer (score 2):

Scala can't use generic tuple with unknown size because Products don's inherit themeselfs. You can try to use Shapeless or Products from play json lib.

Comment: Can you clarify what "don't inherit themselves" means here? I don't see what that means or how it would help.

Comment: Hi :-) The asker didn't specify unknown size but rather any size, which is weaker. For example, shapeless HLists (as you relevantly suggest) are definitely not of unknown size since their size is known at compile time :-)

As Travis Brown, I can't quite figure what you mean in this answer, clarifying would be very helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is [now possible in Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/02/26/tuples-bring-generic-programming-to-scala-3.html) and very straightforward:

```
class MyClass

trait MyTrait[T <: MyClass *: _] {
  def getMyClass(x: T): MyClass = x.head
}
```

The `*:` infix operator is the type level equivalent of the `+:` sequence prepend (or `::` for lists). So we essentially require type `T` to be a tuple such that its first member is of type `MyClass`. Note that the members of generic tuples cannot be retrieved using the usual `_1`, `_2`, ... attributes, but should be accessed using list-like methods (`head`, `tail`, `apply`, etc.). More surprising, these methods are type-safe since they carry precise type information.

Demo:

```
object Test1 extends MyTrait[(MyClass, Int, String)] // Compiles
//object Test2 extends MyTrait[(Int, String)] // Does not compile!
//object Test3 extends MyTrait[EmptyTuple] // Neither does this

val myClass = Test1.getMyClass((new MyClass, 1, "abc"))
summon[myClass.type <:< MyClass] // Compiles
```

Read more about [match types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html), [type inference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/type-inference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit your trait from `Product`, through which you can have `productIterator`, `productArity` and, `productElement` to handle the returned value. Here is an example

```
case class MyClass()

trait MyTrait[T <: Product] {
  def getMyClass(x: T): Option[MyClass] = 
                if(
                     x.productIterator.hasNext 
                                   && 
                     x.productIterator.next().isInstanceOf[MyClass]
                 ){
    Some(x.productIterator.next().asInstanceOf[MyClass])
  } else {
    None
  }
}

case class Test() extends MyTrait[Product]
```

And you can invoke like this

```
Test().getMyClass((MyClass(), 1,3,4,5))
//res1: Option[MyClass] = Some(MyClass())

Test().getMyClass((1,3,4,5))
//res2: Option[MyClass] = None
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for compile time guarantee then this is one of the use cases for
Shapeless,

You need to add Shapeless in your `build.sbt`,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("
  com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3"
)
```

Now, you can use Shapeless to define a typesafe getter which comes with compile time guarantees,

```
scala> import shapeless._
// import shapeless._

scala> import ops.tuple.IsComposite
// import ops.tuple.IsComposite

scala> import syntax.std.tuple._
// import syntax.std.tuple._

scala> case class Omg(omg: String)
// defined class Omg

scala> val myStringTuple = ("All is well", 42, "hope")
// myStringTuple: (String, Int, String) = (All is well,42,hope)

scala> val myOmgTuple = (Omg("All is well"), 42, "hope")
// myOmgTuple: (Omg, Int, String) = (Omg(All is well),42,hope)
```

Now if you want to enrich your tuples with a "first" getter with a specific type then,

```
scala> implicit class GetterForProduct[B <: Product](b: B) {
     |   def getFirst[A](implicit comp: IsComposite[B] { type H = A }): A = b.head
     | }
// defined class GetterForProduct

scala> val myString = myStringTuple.getFirst[String]
// myString: String = All is well

scala>   val myOmgError = myOmgTuple.getFirst[String]
// <console>:24: error: could not find implicit value for parameter comp: shapeless.ops.tuple.IsComposite[(Omg, Int, String)]{type H = String}
//         val myOmgError = myOmgTuple.getFirst[String]
//                                             ^

scala>   val myOmg = myOmgTuple.getFirst[Omg]
// myOmg: Omg = Omg(All is well
```

If you don't need the implicit enrichment and are just looking for a way to "lock" the type in a getter and use it for corresponding types,

```
scala> trait FirstGetterInProduct[A] {
     |   def getFirst[B <: Product](b: B)(implicit comp: IsComposite[B] { type H = A }): A = b.head
     | }
// defined trait FirstGetterInProduct

scala> object firstGetterInProductForString extends FirstGetterInProduct[String]
// defined object firstGetterInProductForString

scala> object firstGetterInProductForOmg extends FirstGetterInProduct[Omg]
// defined object firstGetterInProductForOmg

// Right tuple with right getter,
scala> val myString = firstGetterInProductForString.getFirst(myStringTuple)
// myString: String = All is well

// will fail at compile time for tuple with different type for first
scala> val myOmgError = firstGetterInProductForString.getFirst(myOmgTuple)
// <console>:23: error: could not find implicit value for parameter comp: shapeless.ops.tuple.IsComposite[(Omg, Int, String)]{type H = String}
//          val myOmgError = firstGetterInProductForString.getFirst(myOmgTuple)
//                                                                 ^

scala> val myOmg = firstGetterInProductForOmg.getFirst(myOmgTuple)
// myOmg: Omg = Omg(All is well)
```

Comment: What is the "compile time guarantee" here? The OP has requested that tuples of any length, but only with the 1st element of a specific type, be accepted. (Not my down-vote.)